# Shutdown multiple instances in one command or in script

Tags: google-compute-engine, kubernetes

I am playing with Kubernetes on google compute engines, and I would like to do something that will stop multiple instances at the same time.

I reason of this is, Kubernetes will create a cluster which contains partial common names, for example,

```
kubernetes-minion-group-1
kubernetes-minion-group-2
......
```

Kubernetes has the option to delete all the instances, but I couldn't found the option to shutdown them. I don't want to delete all the instance and recreate the next time.

I understand that the following command will delete one instance,

```
gcloud compute instances stop kubernetes-minion-group-1
```

but how to stop all of them at the same time in one line or maybe in a bash script?  like,

```
gcloud compute instances stop (instances contains 'kubernetes')
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a cleaner way, but something based on the below using [instances list](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/list) might work:

> gcloud compute instances list --filter 'name:kubernetes' --format="csvno-heading"

...which you'd have to parse/grep to get the list. I told it to give a CSV of just the name attributes that match, with no title row (you might be able to play with different [topic formats](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/formats) to get one that works exactly like a spaced list. Then:

> gcloud computes instances stop [list of names]

It seems 'stop' won't take a filter or wildcard. :/